# ASP.NET 2.0 FormsAuthentication Application AuthenticateRequest should ignore WebResource.axd

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-ajax, forms-authentication, iis-express, webresource.axd

I noticed that in my ASP.NET application the Application_AuthenticateRequest event handler is being called several times for the WebResource.axd file.

I have code inside the AuthenticateRequest event handler to generate a modified GenericPrinicpal, that even though it is simple, doesn't need to be executed for the .axd resource.

I'm seeing this behavior while debugging using IIS Express, with the application running in Integrated Pipeline mode.

What is the proper way to handle this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Application_AuthenticateRequest happens for all requests that are handled by .net.

You could test for the extension and bypass if it's .axd.

Comment: Yes, that's the option I've been taking. I was looking for a more elegant solution along the lines of how static content is not processed, or perhaps setting authorization allow users="*"...

Comment: @GoClimbColorado - static content is not processed because those file types are not mapped to the the asp.net pipeline, they just go through IIS.  You can't do that for a .axd because it's a .net module, it has to go through asp.net, thus it will go through AuthenticateRequest.

Comment: @ErikFunkenbusch - does it have any security issue bypassing Application_AuthenticateRequest for .axd files? Like exploiting WebResource.axd to gather information which is only for logged in users?